# Turborepo preparing engine: Could not find "___ROOT___#build" in root turbo.json

Tags: next.js, monorepo, turborepo

When i run `yarn build` i get this error :

```
 ERROR  run failed: error preparing engine: Could not find "___ROOT___#build" in root turbo.json
Turbo error: error preparing engine: Could not find "___ROOT___#build" in root turbo.json
```

here is my turbo.json :

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://turbo.build/schema.json",
  "globalDependencies": ["**/.env.*local", "**/.env"],
  "globalEnv": ["NODE_ENV", "NEXT_PUBLIC_*"],
  "pipeline": {
    "build": {
      "dependsOn": ["^build"],
      "env": ["NEXT_PUBLIC_*"],
      "outputs": ["dist/**", ".next/**", "!.next/cache/**"]
    },
    "db:migrate:deploy": {},
    "db:push": {},
    "db:seed": {},
    "dev": {
      "cache": false,
      "persistent": true
    },
    "generate": {
      "dependsOn": ["^generate"]
    },
    "lint": {}
  }
}
```

Turbo : `1.10.6`

NodeJs : `18`

i dont know why i get this error, it seems that my build command has some issues but it's ok.

I wanted the `yarn build` command to build my monorepo

Comment: What version of turbo do you have? I got the same error with `1.10.6` and  `1.10.3`

Comment: @GianfrancoP. in `package.json` file it says `"turbo": "latest"` so i guess it should be the latest version witch is : `1.10.6`

Comment: Yep, started getting the same here today

Comment: I saw this today on `1.10.6`. Fixed by installing turbo `1.9.9`.

Comment: i downgraded to 1.9.6 – the previous version I had installed – and it works as well